# System InvalidOperationException at System.Lightub.Call on Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, invalidoperationexception

We have a Xamarin Forms app working both in Android and iOS.

It connects to some services in our network and in our office works perfectly. It reaches the services and gets the data without problem.

But now we have sended a phone (with android) to a remote office, the IT people told us that the network at the other office is "exactly like the one we have" and in fact they have acces to the services through web.

But when we try to connect with the app whe get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object 
>       at System.Lightup.Call[TI,VI] (System.Delegate&storage,
>       TI instance, System.String methodName, TV parametyer) [0x0000d]

That exception is launching in httpclient.GetAsync()

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. Go to References of ios Project
2. Edit References
3. Check 'System.Net.Http'

As per [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36713/issue-with-microsoft-http-net-library-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-objec) otherwise take a look at [this one](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36713/issue-with-microsoft-http-net-library-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-objec).

Comment: First of all, as you can see in you point 1 this is a iOS only solution, I think in my question I was pretty specific that this error is ocurring me on Android. Second in the link you post (wich I have also readed, because I know how google works) it says "works in simulator, not in device". In my case it works perfectly in device, but only in our country. Also the references are correct in all of the projects. I'm sorry if I seem rude, but at least take the time to full read my question...

Comment: Sorry, your first line that had iOS and Android on it threw me off - I didn't see the Android right on the end of the question title. It sounds like you have some country/culture specific issues with the app - does it work if they manually set the time/language/culture on the device to the same as the one in your office? Other threads have suggested going back to known good versions of references/dlls/nuget packages, I'm not sure if you've updated any recently but you said they were all good.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm pretty stressed with this fail, I think is a IT problem but my bosses want me to solve it in the app. The phone was sended from our office so it should have the language/culture configuration we sended... not pretty sure about the time... We are gonna check. About the dlls, It was the first I think, but if was that wouldn't it fail on local office too?

Comment: The only thing I can really offer is taking an image of the working phone and loading that onto the other phone. That way you can isolate whether it is hardware or software. If it is hardware then there are things like the network provider, data plan etc. Could be network configuration around firewalls/ports - you’d know better than me. Don’t stress too much though it’ll blow over.